# Scraping an alt tag using Python and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

New to Python, and BeautifulSoup and I am trying to scrape the number of stars that a reviewer leaves a restaurant on Yelp.

So far, I have the following code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

url = "https://www.yelp.com/biz/monkey-house-cafe-huntington-beach"
r = requests.get(url)
page_soup = soup(r.content, "lxml")

review_container = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": "review-content"})
review_container[0]
```

When I run that code in Jupyter Notebook, I get the following, that corresponds to the most recent review:

```
<div class="review-content">
<div class="biz-rating biz-rating-large clearfix">
<div>
<div class="i-stars i-stars--regular-5 rating-large" title="5.0 star rating">
<img alt="5.0 star rating" class="offscreen" height="303" src="https://s3-media1.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/srv0/yelp_design_web/41341496d9db/assets/img/stars/stars.png" width="84"/>
</div>
</div>
<span class="rating-qualifier">
    5/10/2017
</span>
</div>
<p lang="en">This place is really fun and cute. I was happy to discover it.. <br/><br/>They also have beer and wine here, which is kind of a nice bonus. The sangria is good..</p>
</div>
```

My question is how can I get the number of stars from each review?

I am thinking that it would be best to scrape the contents of the `img alt` tag but I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: Also, I have noticed that each star rating has a different class name and so from the example above, the tag of the five-star rating is named `div class="i-stars i-stars--regular-5 rating-large`.  However, a one-star rating will have a different `div class` name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to extract from `img alt` you can use :

```
review_container[0].select('img')[0]['alt'].split()[0]
'5.0'
```

Comment: if this answer is helpful, please mark as correct answer for future users @gaguinaldo

Answer (score 0):

```
float(review_container[0].find("img")["alt"][:3])
```